# Batch Script for Copy Directory to Thumb Drive Looking for Directory by Date and Creating if not there

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy my "C:\PWE\FaxesOutgoing" directory to my "E:\" (a thumb drive)

I need the script to look to see if the E:\ has an existing directory with the current days date (ie: E:\MMDDYY). If so, copy any files in C:\PWE\FaxesOutgoing to that directory IF not already there.

If a directory with the current date does not exist, then one needs to be created and then the files copied to it.

I will be setting this batch file up to run in a scheduler that runs every 30 min.

Comment: Do you have code that you have tried to write?

Answer (score 0):

```
set drive=e:\
set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
set day=%date:~7,2%

if not exist "%drive%%month%%day%%year%" MD "%drive%%month%%day%%year%"

xcopy c:\pwe\faxesoutgoing "%drive%%month%%day%%year%"
```

Not tested, but should be close.